# Insert img where clicked

Tags: php, jquery, css

How can I insert a img wherever I click on the page?

I have the following code:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var string = x +','+ y;
    //alert(string);
    $('.marker').css(
        {
            'left': x +'px',
            'top': y +'px'
        },{
              duration:1000,
          })        
});
```

But this only moves the img around the page. I need to add multiple copies and POST to php url.

Thanks!

Comment: i'm not sure it's clear how your POST is related to the image insertion.  can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. What I meant was post the position of the img to store into a db. But I should figure that out now as per undefineds answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the element.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var string = x + ',' + y;
    //alert(string);
    $('.marker:first').clone().css({
        'left': x + 'px',
        'top': y + 'px'
    }).appendTo('body')
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xarGV/

Answer (score 2):

You mean this ?

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var string = x +','+ y;
    //alert(string);
    $('.marker:first').clone().css({
        'left': x +'px',                                        
        'top': y +'px',
        'position':'absolute'
    }).appendTo('body')      
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Avh6V/4/).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn’t insert the img where its clicked. It only inserts a new img